# xrandr HDMI port via USB-C docking station detected as DP. No signal on monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 22.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

**UPDATED**

There is no signal on my external monitor, when I connect it to my Lenovo X390 Yoga laptop. I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it. The Laptop does not have a graphics card and uses the integrated graphics of the `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U` chip.

The laptop previously worked with this monitor on Windows 10. The monitor works with a PC and a different laptop, the former uses Windows 10, the latter also Ubuntu 22.04.

I now switched from Wayland to X11 and my xrandr output shows something interesting: Even though the connection is

```
[Monitor] --HDMI-- [docking station] --USB-C-- [laptop]
```

xrandr recognizes the monitor under the `DP-2-1` port. Unfortunately my docking station does not have a display port so I could check it would work then.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1175, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+95 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.02    48.02  
   1680x1050     60.02  
   1400x1050     60.02  
   1600x900      60.02  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      60.02  
   1280x960      60.02  
   1440x810      60.02  
   1368x768      60.02  
   1280x800      60.02  
   1280x720      60.02  
   1024x768      60.02  
   960x720       60.02  
   928x696       60.02  
   896x672       60.02  
   1024x576      60.02  
   960x600       60.02  
   960x540       60.02  
   800x600       60.02  
   840x525       60.02  
   864x486       60.02  
   700x525       60.02  
   800x450       60.02  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       60.02  
   640x480       60.02  
   720x405       60.02  
   684x384       60.02  
   640x360       60.02  
   512x384       60.02  
   512x288       60.02  
   480x270       60.02  
   400x300       60.02  
   432x243       60.02  
   320x240       60.02  
   360x202       60.02  
   320x180       60.02  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 connected primary 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 255mm x 255mm
   1680x1050     60.00 +
   3840x2160     30.00    29.97  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03*   70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**Question**
How can I tell xrandr that the `DP-2-1` is actually `HDMI-1`?

Comment: Updated with new findings.

Answer (score 0):

did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue with the t490s and think pad ultra dock.

I did try all firmware updates for dock and laptop, no changes under Linux. On widows 11, some times it just work, and some times not.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I'll keep this y thread updated if I do

Comment: This should preferably be a comment.